Sending byte array to Speech-To-Text API (Azure)
I am recording voice on the browser and sending it to my API, which is going to send data to Speech-To-Text API (Azure).
I keep getting NoMach from the API.
Here is my browser code:

let languageCode = "da-DK";
let mediaRecorder;
let audioChunks = [];
let isRecording = false;


function startRecording() {
    var constraints = {
        audio: {
            sampleRate: 16000,
            channelCount: 1
        }
    };

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(function (stream) {
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
                audioChunks.push(e.data);
            }
            mediaRecorder.onstop = function () {
                const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                    const audioBytes = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
                    var base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, audioBytes));

                    voiceToText(languageCode, base64String);

                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(audioBlob);
            }
            mediaRecorder.start();
            recordButton.disabled = true;
            stopButton.disabled = false;
            playButton.disabled = true;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error('Error recording audio: ' + err);
        });
}

function voiceToText(myLanguageCode, wavData) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://localhost:7058/api/Conversation/postVoiceToString",
        contentType: "application/json", // Set Content-Type header
        data: JSON.stringify({ // Stringify the data
            LanguageCode: myLanguageCode,
            WAV: wavData
        }),
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
}


I know my API works, and when I send test data with voiceToText(languageCode, base64String); in js then it also works. but when I record the data and then send it, it says NoMach.

btoa() is only intended for ASCII strings, where yout fromCharChode is going to work with UTF-16.  Try var base64String = new TextEncoder('base64').encode(audioBytes);

now i am getting error 400 from server.

TextEncoder API is primarily intended for encoding strings, not binary data, into various formats such as UTF-8, UTF-16, or base64.

I need to send as byte array string. when i send my tested data (eks. "UklGRqhPBABXQVZ... much longer.") then it's work

@Suresh Chikkam.... agree :)

data: JSON.stringify({
LanguageCode: myLanguageCode,
ByteArrayString: byteArrayString // Send byte array string to API
}),

The audio data is recorded and stored in audioChunks.
When recording is stopped, the audio chunks are combined into a single Blob.
The Blob is read as an array buffer, and then converted to a Uint8Array.
The Uint8Array is then converted to a byte array string using toString().
The byte array string is sent to your API endpoint using AJAX.

@AbbasAnwar If your hardcoded byte array string is working, it means your server expects the data in a specific format that might be the issue.

Strings are just byte arrays, though expected to conform to certain rules which will get violated feeding raw binary wav data into it. My comment missed the String.fromCharCode() which is probably the main problem in that a wav byte array will likely contain something recognized as a string termination. Have a look here which would work for audio data: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982712/convert-binary-data-to-base64-with-javascript) There are option using encodeURIComponent + decodeURI or a FileReader with a Blob wrapping the byte array.

@AbbasAnwar were you able to resolve this, we are kind of blocked at same point.

The limitations and constraints of btoa() and the complexities involved in handling character encoding in JavaScript.

Thanks @Steve Py for the insights, adding to your statement btoa() is intended for ASCII strings and fromCharCode works with UTF-16, it may not handle all byte values correctly. But Using TextEncoder API it primarily intended for encoding strings, not binary data.


I need to send as byte array string. when i send my tested data (eks. "UklGRqhPBABXQVZ... much longer.") then it's work

If the hardcoded byte array string is working, it means your server expects the data in a specific format.

If you need to send the audio data as a byte array string, we can directly convert the Uint8Array to a string representing the byte array.

let languageCode = "da-DK";
let mediaRecorder;
let audioChunks = [];
let isRecording = false;

function startRecording() {
    var constraints = {
        audio: {
            sampleRate: 16000,
            channelCount: 1
        }
    };

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(function (stream) {
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
                audioChunks.push(e.data);
            }
            mediaRecorder.onstop = function () {
                const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                    const audioBytes = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
                    const byteArrayString = audioBytesToString(audioBytes);
                    voiceToText(languageCode, byteArrayString);
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(audioBlob);
            }
            mediaRecorder.start();
            // Update UI or disable/enable buttons accordingly
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error('Error recording audio: ' + err);
        });
}

function audioBytesToString(bytes) {
    return Array.from(bytes).map(byte => String.fromCharCode(byte)).join(',');
}

function voiceToText(myLanguageCode, byteArrayString) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://localhost:7058/api/Conversation/postVoiceToString",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            LanguageCode: myLanguageCode,
            ByteArrayString: byteArrayString
        }),
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
}


audioBytesToString function converts the Uint8Array containing audio bytes into a string representing the byte array. Each byte is converted to a character using String.fromCharCode, and the resulting characters are joined together into a comma-separated string.

Then send this byte array string (byteArrayString) to the server along with the language code using an AJAX POST request.


Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74183536

Writing to an existing Uint8Array

How to Make the JavaScript "btoa()" Method Work With Multibyte Strings? - Designcise



Now i am getting byteArrayString as ,E,ß,£,,B,,,,B,÷,,,B,ò,,,B,ó,,,B,,,w,e,b,m,B,,,,B,
